# pfSense IPsec VPN setup (Log error: racoon: INFO: unsupported PF_KEY message REGISTER)

Tags: vpn, ipsec, pfsense

Good morning,
I'm trying to setup an IPSec Tunnel on a pfSense firewall.
I have 2 interfaces configured:

- WAN (public firewall IP: ***.***.***.***/31)
- LAN (internal static IPs: 192.168.104.0/29)

I set up the tunnel but I always get error on the VPN startup.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!

**pfSense LOG:**

- Nov 7 11:38:31    racoon: INFO: unsupported PF_KEY message REGISTER
- Nov 7 11:38:31    racoon: [Self]: INFO: 95.110.168.135[500] used as isakmp port (fd=15)
- Nov 7 11:38:31    racoon: [Self]: INFO: 95.110.168.135[500] used for NAT-T
- Nov 7 11:38:31    racoon: [Self]: INFO: 95.110.168.135[4500] used as isakmp port (fd=14)
- Nov 7 11:38:31    racoon: [Self]: INFO: 95.110.168.135[4500] used for NAT-T
- Nov 7 11:38:31    racoon: INFO: Reading configuration from "/var/etc/racoon.conf"
- Nov 7 11:38:31    racoon: INFO: @(#)This product linked OpenSSL 0.9.8n 24 Mar 2010 (http://www.openssl.org/)
- Nov 7 11:38:31    racoon: INFO: @(#)ipsec-tools 0.8.0 (http://ipsec-tools.sourceforge.net)

**IPSec Phase 1:**

- Interface: WAN
- Remote gateway: peer public IP
- Authentication method: Mutual PSK
- My Identifier: IP Address (my public IP)
- Peer Identifier: IP Address (peer public IP)
- Pre-shared key: **********************
- Policy generation: Default
- Proposal Checking: Default
- Encryption algorithm: 3DES
- Hash algoritm: MD5
- DH key group: 2
- NAT Traversal: Enable

**IPSec Phase 2:**

- Mode: Tunnel
- Local Network: LAN
- Remote Netwoek: Network (192.168.30.0/24)
- Protocol: ESP
- Encryprion algorithm: 3DES
- Hash algorytm: MD5
- PFS key group: off

Comment: I finally find out the solution.
Trying to ping the VPN private address from peer VPN, the traffic was one way. So the peer didn't receive any answer.

I created rules on my pfSense to **allow ICMP to VPN (LAN interface)** and things seem to go right now.
The tunnel works properly.